# Insert large amount of data in HSQL

Tags: memory, databaselink, databases

I create HSQL database with one table

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
dbLocation="c:\\work\\hsqlTest\\";
dbName="testDB";
dbServer=SQLServerLaunch[{dbName->dbLocation}]
dbConnectionObject=JDBC["HSQL(Server)","localhost/"<>dbName];
dbConnection=OpenSQLConnection[dbConnectionObject,"Name"->dbName,"Username"->"sa"];
```

But inserting large amount of data produce different errors with different insert. For example:

```
data=RandomReal[{-10,10},{500000,1}];
SQLInsert[dbConnection,"TestTableDouble",{"c1"},data];
```

produce error:

JDBC::error: connection exception: connection failure: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded >>

or

> JDBC::error: GC overhead limit exceeded >>

How can I avoid this error?

PS: some inserts do not produce error

**Add:**
With SQLite I have the same problem, but with inserting `1000000` rows

Comment: Did you try partitioning the data and inserting it in batches?

Comment: @Pickett Yes, after inserting some amount of data totally I get the error too

Comment: OK, HSQL keeps all data in the memory and perhaps if you deal with big data sets it could be worth it to install MySQL or use SQLite and avoid this problem in the process. But if you really want to do this I think you can use [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/giving-jlink-huge-memory-by-default) technique.

Comment: @Pickett Agreed.  You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two possible solutions are

- <s>Use MySQL, SQLite or any other database that is *not* an in-memory database. HSQL keeps all its data in the memory at all times.</s> I'm leaving this for future visitors since there is a version of HSQL that is built in that is in-memory, although that was not the case for the OP.
- Increase the Java heap size by using the same technique that is used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/giving-jlink-huge-memory-by-default) (you may or may not want to put it in init.m though).

Comment: `HSQL(Server)` is not memory database, but `HSQL(Memory)` was. It's problem cause the `JDBC` connection wich suppose launching `JVM` for any database database driver in `JDBCDriverNames[]`

Comment: @molekyla777 I stand corrected. `JDBC` needs Java and therefore JVM. Did you try increasing the Java heap size  as in the link I gave you?

Comment: yes, I try to increase Java heap size. It solve problem. Now I testing JVM with large heap size.